# SSRS 2008 - Graph - Negative Logarithmic Scale

Tags: reporting-services, graph, ssrs-2008, logarithm, negative-number

I didn't think this one would be complicated.  I want the Y Axis on my Graph in SSRS 2008 to start at -100.  I set the Minimum to -100, but it still starts at 1.  Is a negative logarithmic scale possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, apparently.  Stupid math.  Had to attach a Linear graph, y-scaled from 0 to -20, below the Log one.  Grr.